# Django static Files not loaded on Docker?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, static-files

I am using Django 3.0.6 and want to dockerize my project. everything is worked fine except static files. Static files are loaded completely when I run my project normally. But, after dockerization, they are not loaded and throw a 404 error.
my project layout as follow:

```
    ├── nginx
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   └── nginx.conf
    ├── src
         ├── applications
         ├── configuration
         │   ├── asgi.py
         │   ├── __init__.py
         │   ├── __pycache__
         │   ├── settings.py
         │   ├── urls.py
         │   └── wsgi.py
         ├── Dockerfile
         ├── manage.py
         ├── requirements.txt
         ├── static
         │   ├── build
         │   ├── images
         │   └── vendors
         └── templates
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV SRC_DIR=/var/www/project/src
RUN mkdir -p $SRC_DIR
WORKDIR $SRC_DIR
ADD ./requirements.txt $SRC_DIR/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . $SRC_DIR
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./src
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 4 configuration.wsgi"
    env_file: ./src/.environment
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/project/src
      - ./src/static:/var/www/project/src/static
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/project/src
      - ./src/static:/var/www/project/src/static
    depends_on:
      - web
```

nginx.conf:

```
    upstream view {
        server web:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://view;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
                alias /var/www/project/src/static;
        }

   }
```

I don't know What the problem is. please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Try use root instead of alias on static location, also on you docker-compose you don't need to specify ./src/static because it's included on you first volume ./src. hope it helps

Comment: Do you mean: root /var/www/project/src/static ? it doesn't  work.

Comment: @Rahman: did you find out ? I have the same problem

Comment: You can try running collectstatic in your Dockerfile if you are runing with Debug=False:
`RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear`

Answer (score 0):

I installed nginx normally and installed the others with docker and it is working now.